# Factory of factories?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, factory

I have concrete factory classes which implement `MyFactory` interface. I  want to get concrete factory objects based on parameter. How to do this?

One way is to create factory of factories[FoF],  and FoF would be parameterized factory.

Is there any more elegant way to do this?

This is purely intellectual exercise, I am not facing any problem in my project.

Comment: I used a template to accomplish similar in something I am working on, but that *only* works if the factories just serve as a generic way to create polymorphic classes. If any of the classes need set up specially, you'll need to specialize the template for those cases, which could get messy.

Comment: I am having a hard time imagining what business problem this "factory of factories" could be aimed at solving.  Either a clear use case or some code might help clear things up.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Say, user selects some bike[having some ID] in racing game. I want to use factory of the selected bike, to make the bike. I will pass the bike ID to FoF and it will return me appropriate factory object.

Comment: Would a function that returns `MyFactory` object created on heap be ok? The function would take the `ID` and create the appropriate `Factory` object.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a regular factory to take the bike ID and return a bike?  In the case you mentioned it sounds like the FoF would return a "factory" which is only capable of making one thing...which seems odd.  You could make your bike objects implement a `clone()` method, if you need to be able to make several bikes of the same type.

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes concrete factory can return different things[different configuration of same type] but of the same type. Otherwise by definition it will not be concrete factory if it returns more than one type. `clone()` seems more elegant than FoF, But to `clone()` the bike, we will need to create them first. We have only shifted the problem at different place. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Say, in GTA like game, how are different vehicles, cars, bikes, motorcycles, etc. generated? Do they hard code it? or to spawn random vehicle on next turn, say,`getVehicleindustry(randomVehicleIDgenerator)`, call `buildVehicle()` on the returned factory?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the Abstract Factory pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to merge the two layers of factories, that would of course be the preferable solution. This would be possible if the have the same lifecycle.

**If they don't then creating a factory of factories is fine.** There's no problem with the pattern itself, the pattern can be nested. You could even create a factory of factories of factories (please don't) and it would work.

**However, you should find a suitable name for the factory of factories, so that the intent is clear.** Factory of factories doesn't sound like a good name to me. Choosing a name that communicates the behavior within your problem domain is better than a purely pattern-oriented name.

---

Edit: Someone suggested that you take a look at the abstract factory pattern in the comments to the question. While it is certainly a useful pattern, and one that a good software engineer should know about, **an abstract factory is not a factory of factories:** The pattern abstracts a group of related factories, but is not about creating them. Still, learning about it will help.

Comment: It was my suggestion to check the abstract factory pattern. It's definitely not the same as factory of factories, however judging from the problem description it might be a good alternative to having factory of factories (which definitely raises a couple of eyebrows). E.g., instead of parametrizing factory creation, more OO-oriented solution can be to specialize an abstract factory with concrete derived factories. It's even possible to unite both approaches.